# Javascript - AutoComplete Search

Tags: javascript, image, performance, load, lag

I have an autocomplete search field connected to MySQL database to retrieve values, it is coded for a java game ( It has items id, name, and picture )

20,000 items has been added. It is supposed to be a lookup, and actually, when you click on an option it prints more information about the item like, it's in-game price and description etc.

The problem is that it lags and takes time because there are 20,000 pictures being loaded, and I kind of want it to show pictures so the player can find things easier. I do know that by just removing pictures from showing it won't lag.

A new idea I came up with is setting the minimum characters to 3 before starting the search, which is the minimum item letter. This will help a little to reduce lagging as if the item's name is "Party Hat" the player will need to write "par" or whatever so it will only load like 100-500 values, instead of just typing "a" and load at least 70-80% of the values as most of them contain "a", Or "swo" for "sword".

Some other people suggested compressing the pictures, but they are actually 18mb for the 20,000 pictures which is about 1kb per picture?

The search field only loads pictures of the results, so if you keep the website open for 1 hour, none of the images will be loaded because the server has not made a call or a request for a specific picture to load. If you type something it loads all the images that matches your search which are the results. (100-1000 or whatever)

Any suggestions or ideas to solve this ?

An example of how it looks like can be found here..

[Example 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FgN5y.png)

[Example 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B9apj.png)

Thanks for reading!

Comment: One thing I have done in the past with autocomplete type fields is wait a second or 2 after the user stops typing before loading suggestions. This way if they type 6 characters your code is not going to try and load autocomplete results for characters 3, 4, & 5, just once that have stopped typing at character 6 which should mean even less matches in the results.

Answer (score 0):

The way to optimize this is to prioritize the images that come first in the dropdown, that is what the user will normally see. You can render a spinner for all cases that would be preloaded since the beginning.

When the user starts typing and you receive the records from the database, you set the spinner as the image for all the items, and then load the images for the first 6 items (for example), when all are finished (or errored), load the next ones, etc. If the user scrolls, you have to calculate which items are being displayed (there are libraries for this), but if all of the items have the same size you could do it by the percentage scrolled, and prioritize then these ones.

Most of the times the user will not scroll right away so the UX will improve a lot. This is a handy construct to check if the images are loaded:

```
const preloadImage = (imageSrc) => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    if (!imageSrc) {
      resolve();
      return;
    }

    const img = new Image();

    img.src = imageSrc;
    img.onload = resolve;
    img.onerror = resolve;
  });
};

const preloadImages = (imagesSrc) => {
  return Promise.all(imagesSrc.map(preloadImage));
};
```

Setting the minimum to 3 characters is a good idea, but you should also [debounce](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#debounce) the requests so, for example, you wait 500 ms before requesting the server to check if the value of the input changed, in case the user is still typing.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. I will try implementing this method and put a 500ms delay. It will make an incredible change. Thanks!

Comment: Cool, please let me know if it works and if the answer has helpful